# Replacing SQL not exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
(
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            case_plans
        WHERE
            NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    case_plan_needs
                    JOIN case_plan_need_goals ON case_plan_need_goals.case_plan_need_id = case_plan_needs.id
                WHERE
                    case_plan_needs.case_plan_id = case_plans.id
                    AND case_plan_need_goals.deleted_at IS NULL));
```

Is there a way to write this without the Not Exists clause?

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide the `CREATE` statements for the tables, sample data as `INSERT` statements. Include the desired result with that sample data in tabular text from. Describe the problem because of which you want to get rid of the `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join` as follows:

```
SELECT distinct cp.*
  FROM case_plans cp
  Left join case_plan_needs cpn
    On cpn.case_plan_id = cp.id
  Left join case_plan_need_goals cpng
   On cpng.case_plan_need_id = cpn.id
  And cpng.deleted_at IS NULL
Where cpng.case_plan_need_id is null;
```

Comment: The `select distinct` is not necessary.

Comment: It is necessary in case it has multiple records in the left joined tables.

Comment: This does not seem to be working. It's returning more rows than the original query

Comment: What is the primary key of table `case_plan_need_goals`? Use it in `cpng.pk_column is null` in where clause

Comment: @Popeye . . . That is not possible if there is no match.

Comment: Can you please explain about your last comment a little bit more @GordonLinoff

Comment: @Popeye . . . The `WHERE` clause is choosing rows where the left joins have no matches.  That means that no rows in the first table are getting duplicated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  if `case_plan_needs` table has multiple matches and no match found in the table `case_plan_need_goals` then rows will be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

A literal translation should be:

```
SELECT case_plans.*
FROM case_plans
   LEFT JOIN (case_plan_needs
                 JOIN case_plan_need_goals
                    ON case_plan_need_goals.case_plan_need_id = case_plan_needs.id)
      ON case_plan_needs.case_plan_id = case_plans.id
         AND case_plan_need_goals.deleted_at IS NULL
WHERE case_plan_needs.case_plan_id IS NULL;
```

But there is nothing wrong with using `NOT EXISTS` (unless there are NULLs returned by the subquery), it may even be more efficient.